# Moving anchor tag down?

Tags: html, css

[image]

How do I move the "delete" anchor tag down so it lines up better with the rest of the controls on this line?

Below is my HTML:

```
    <strong><em>Items with an individual value less than $500 should be scheduled below.</em></strong>

<div class="dialogSection">
    <div style="float:left" class="first">
        <label for="unscheduledDescription" style="display:inline-block">
            Description of Equipment
        </label>
        <input id="unscheduledDescription" type="text" data-bind="value: coverage.unscheduledDescription" class="input input-lg" style="margin: 6px; padding: 5px;" />
    </div>
    <div style="float:left" class="first">
        <label for="unscheduledLimit" style="display:inline-block">
            Limit
        </label>
        <input id="unscheduledLimit" type="text" data-bind="value: coverage.unscheduledLimit" class="input input-number" style="margin: 6px; padding: 5px;" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: deleteUnscheduledCmd, clickBubble: false">
            delete
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: try `line-height` or `margin-top` or  `padding-top`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see that the `<a>`is wrapped with a div , just add an id to the div and apply some styling:

```
 <div id = "del">
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: deleteUnscheduledCmd, clickBubble: false">
            delete
        </a>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#del{
    padding-top:10px;
}
```

Working fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/wgsrrbav/

*Let me know if i helped :)*

Comment: This worked for me. Honestly I tried different combinations of padding and margins all over the div area. I just could not get the right combination.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Richard glad i coul help your out :)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely *Ashish Mehtha's* answer is better. Another option you can add float:left and margin- top style to the div ( for margin-top style instead of 10px you can add something in pecentage like 1% to make it responsive )

`<div style="float:left; margin-top:10px;">
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: deleteUnscheduledCmd, clickBubble: false">
            delete
        </a>
    </div>`

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5w0fyr7q/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.dialogSection > div {
  display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
 <strong><em>Items with an individual value less than $500 should be scheduled below.</em></strong>

<div class="dialogSection">
    <div class="first">
        <label for="unscheduledDescription" style="display:inline-block">
            Description of Equipment
        </label>
        <input id="unscheduledDescription" type="text" data-bind="value: coverage.unscheduledDescription" class="input input-lg" style="margin: 6px; padding: 5px;" />
    </div>
    <div class="first">
        <label for="unscheduledLimit" style="display:inline-block">
            Limit
        </label>
        <input id="unscheduledLimit" type="text" data-bind="value: coverage.unscheduledLimit" class="input input-number" style="margin: 6px; padding: 5px;" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: deleteUnscheduledCmd, clickBubble: false">
            delete
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Simple Add Display:inline-block; property in inline div. No need to add float:left property to particular Div.

```
.dialogSection > div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```